# Could intentionally leggy seedlings followed by transplanting result in stronger root systems?

Tags: seedlings, roots, transplanting

While researching how to save my leggy tomatoes, I've learned that they can have the extra stem buried during a transplant to "reset" the height, and this buried stem will then grow roots of its own. Assuming you could provide adequate light after transplanting (i.e. they were intentionally given less light than was available to induce legginess), could this opportunity for rapid root creation actually be a *good* thing?

I could imagine the induced stress which resulted in accelerated growth could be utilized to create a seedling with a stronger and healthier root system, benefitting the plant once it bounces back from transplanting. Or would the poor lighting and transplant stress outweigh the benefit that more roots could bring?

Comment: Intentionally inducing stress on plants to promote root growth may not be a recommended practice as it can have negative outcome such as stunted growth and disease susceptibility. Providing optimal growing conditions is a better approach to promote healthy growth and strong roots.

Comment: @FalseIdentity some plants benefit from trimming to simulate growth, so not all stress is bad. Is there a reason  root growth is different than this?

Comment: Root growth is different from trimming or pruning because roots absorb water and nutrients from soil. Damage or stress to the roots can negatively impact the plant's overall health. While root pruning can stimulate new growth, it should be done carefully during dormant season or non-active growth periods. It's important to approach any form of plant stress, including trimming or root pruning, with care and consider the specific needs of the plant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For most of us, as well as we can (afford to) do for the seedling still leaves plenty to bury when transplanting.

Intentionally doing worse by the plant would be unwise.

You don't have to limit what you bury when transplanting to bare stem, by the way.